# How many kernels in ipython notebook

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

How many kernels is it safe to open in ipython notebook? I'm downloading a lot of data so to make the process go faster I am using multiple kernels.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on your machine and general setup. Generally downloading data is not dependant on your hardware but on the network bandwidth. And your question will not be specific to IPython notebook.